# How to assign values in a for loop from a list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, assign

I have three vertices of a rectangle and need to find the fourth vertex, and I need to find the missing vertex for N numbers of rectangles.

Sadly, I could not figure out how I can assign the vertices after the first rectangle :/.

Here is the example text file for input:

```
2      # '2' is the number of rectangles.
5 5    #        (x1, y1)
5 7    #        (x2, y2)
7 5    #        (x3, y3)
30 20  #        (x1, y1)
10 10  #        (x2, y2)
10 20  #        (x3, y3)
       #   (there could be more '**vertices**' and more than '**2**' cases)
```

Here was my approach:

```
import sys

def calculate(num):
  x1 = lines[n].split()[0]
  y1 = lines[n].split()[1]
  x2 = lines[n+1].split()[0]
  y2 = lines[n+1].split()[1]
  x3 = lines[n+2].split()[0]
  y3 = lines[n+2].split()[1]
  print x1, y1
  print x2, y2
  print x3, y3
  #Planning to write codes for calculation & results below inside this function.

readlines = sys.stdin.readlines()    # reads
num = int(lines[0])                  # assigns the number of cases

for i in range(0, num):
  item += 1
  calculate(item)                    # Calls the above function
```

When I run this code, I get the following:

```
5 5
5 7
7 5 

5 7
7 5
30 20
```

What I wanted to get was:

```
5 5
5 7
7 5

30 20
10 10
10 20
```

Comment: Using the `grouper` recipe shown on the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) documentation page, you could easily (and efficiently) consume your file in chunks of three.

Comment: It's my first time signing up and posting my question here. I do really appreciate your help!

Comment: What is `'n`? where did you declare it? it seems that the code you posted above is not complete

Comment: My bad. Yes, you are right. It should be 'n' instead of 'num'! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
item += 3
```

inside your loop.

---

Looking at it again, that's not enough to make it work. You want to pass the line numbers

```
1, 4, 7, 10 .....
```

to your `calculate` function. You can do this with the 3-argument version of `range`

```
for iLine in range( 1, 3*num-1, 3):
    calculate( iLine)
```

The third argument tells it to skip by 3 each time, and you need to start at line #1, not #0, as line #0 contains your count.

You also need to get the upper limit right. The final value you want to pass into `calculate` is actually `3*num-2`, but remember that the `range` function does not include the upper limit, so we can use (highest desired value + 1) there, which is where the `3*num-1` comes from.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I tried that, but it gave me an out of range error.  Here is what I got 7 5,  30 20,  10 10

Comment: Yes, I was confused by the loop variable being `i` and passing the variable `item` into your `calculate` function. If you loop over the same variable that you pass to `calculate`, like in my `iLine` example, I think it's clearer.

Comment: Thank you again Jonathan. I tried as you suggested, and it worked perfect! I really appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the code above is not your complete code, but I think you should correct it in your real code as follows:
instead of `item +=1` you should write `item = 1+ i*3`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @DavidC you're welcome. In stackoverflow when someone answers your question and you find it helpful  please like the answer. Thanks

Comment: Oh okay, I would be happy to like your answer for your help. How do I click like? I clicked on the up arrow now! :) Thank you.

Comment: You can like by clicking the up arrow in in the left hand side of my answer

Comment: I already did that, and when I click on it, it says that I need to have more than 15 reputations in order to show it publicly. I am not sure if that counted or not. Anyways, thank you for your help!

Comment: Um, will that work? I think you'd want either `item += 3` _or_ `item = 3*i+1`.

Comment: @Jonathan In the code that DavidC has posted, yes it should work, the first three cordinates start at index=1 so `item` is initially set to 1 and with `for i in range(0, num):`  item will be 1,4,...., so it works.

Comment: @alivar - Oh, sorry, I missed that it would work when there are just one or two sets of vertices. But the question says that there could be more than 2 cases and I don't see how your code could work then, or  even how it could be adapted to work when `num > 2`. If there is a way maybe you could update your answer so it would handle the `num > 2` cases as well

Comment: @Jonathan my answer is not restricted to num=2! can you show me how it's limited to num =2?

Comment: @alivar - The formatting didn't work as a comment so I added it as an answer below.

Comment: @Jonathan Oh, sorry, this a mistake, I meant  `item = i*3`

Comment: I eddited the answer

Answer (score 1):

@Avilar - This is what happens in your code when `num > 2`
Your code suggestion is like this:

```
item = 1
for i in range(0, num):
   item += i*3
```

As we go through the loop

```
i = 0
item += 0 --> item = 1
```

then

```
i = 1
item += 3 --> item = 4
```

then

```
i = 2
item += 2*3 --> item = 10
```

then

```
i = 3
item += 3*3 --> item = 19
```

then

```
i = 4
item += 3*4 --> item = 31
```

You will generate the numbers

```
1, 4, 10, 19, 31, 46, 64
```

when we want

```
1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19
```